# loading image to jsp (struts2) from database

Tags: database, image, jsp, struts2

I have problem with loading image from database to jsp view. It looks like action are execute but stop in middle.
I log when execute() method start and when its end. In log file i can see start this method but there are no end.

I have action:

```
public class ShowImageAction extends BaseAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ShowImageAction.class);

    private int id;

    public String execute() {
        LOG.info("Enter execute()");
        MessageBean messageBean = (MessageBean) sessionParameters
                .get(SessionParameters.BANNER_EDIT);

        IFiles filesEJB = EJBLocator.getFiles();
        if (messageBean != null) {
            id = messageBean.getBannerId();
        }

        FileBean file = filesEJB.file(id);

        LOG.info("Id = " + id);
        if (file != null) {
            byte[] bytes = null;
            try {
                LOG.info("File: name = " + file.getName() + ". type = "
                        + file.getType());
                if (file.getImage() != null) {
                    bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file.getImage());
                    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext
                            .getResponse();
                    response.setContentType(file.getType());
                    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                    out.write(bytes);
                    out.close();
                } else {
                    LOG.info("execute(): Nie udało się pobrać pliku z bazy danych!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error(e);
            }
        } else {
            LOG.info("execute(): Nie udało się pobrać pliku z bazy danych!");
        }
        LOG.info("Exit execute()");
        return NONE;
    }
```

jsp:

```
    <div class="OneFilteringRow">
        Podgląd<br />
        <img src="/ebok-bm/ShowImageAction" alt="Podgląd banera" />
    </div>
```

struts.xml

```
    <action name="ShowImageAction"
            class="pl.bm.action.content.ShowImageAction">
    </action>
```

Comment: If you are sure, your action class give you back a picture, try this `<img src="<s:url action='/ebok-bm/ShowImageAction' />" />`

Comment: Set a break point and step through?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in:

```
FileBean file = filesEJB.file(id);
```

I get bytes from database and try to save it to tmpFile. Now I get bytes and writes them to a temporary file and immediately transmit it to the action and everything is ok.
Now I have:

```
    FileBean file = filesEJB.file(id);

    LOG.info("Id = " + id);
    if (file != null) {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            LOG.info("File: name = " + file.getName() + ". type = "
                    + file.getType());
            if (file.getImage() != null) {
                **bytes = file.getImage();**
                HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext
                        .getResponse();
                response.setContentType(file.getType());
                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                out.write(bytes);
                out.close();
            } else {
                LOG.info("execute(): Nie udało się pobrać pliku z bazy danych!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to your own result implements Result class and write output here.Other in `struts.xml`action result type specified own with approx mate parameters.
refer:[generate own image as action result](http://lkreddy.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-write-our-own-result-type-in.html)